# Transpose on Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

i have data frame like this:

```
ID   A     B    C
1    2001  10   5 
1    2002  15   6
```

I want to do transpose so the result look like:

```
ID   B_2001    C_2001   B_2002     C_2002
1     10          5       15         6
```

Is there any way to do it with pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `pivot`:

```
# pivot gives you correct data structure
out = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='A')

# rename the columns
out.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, x)) for x in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
    B_2001  B_2002  C_2001  C_2002
ID                                
1       10      15       5       6
```

Comment: thank you but can I get the result without changing the order of column ```A``` so the column will be ```ID   B_2001    C_2001   B_2002     C_2002```

Comment: @kj14 do `out = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='A').sort_index(level=[1,0], axis=1)`